# Grails Detached Criteria with Composite key

Tags: grails, composite-key, detachedcriteria, createcriteria

Domain Setup
.

```
Study {
    Long id
    String name
    Site site
    USState state
    ...
}
```

.

```
Site {
    Long id
    String name
    ...
}
```

.

```
Resource {
    Long id
    String name
    Boolean active
    USState state
    ...
}
```

.

```
SiteResource {
    id composite: ['site', 'resource']
    Site site
    Resource resource
}
```

I have 2 lists that get populated for the Study.
One is a list of currently associated Resources to the Site
Another is a list of available Resources that can be associated to the Site. These available Resources are determined by being Active = true and within the same USState as the Study

I'm trying to write a criteria to get this to work but cannot seem to get it. I need to show all Resources that are Active, in the same USState as the Study and not currently associated with the Site (the current associations are in the first table)

```
return Resource.createCriteria().list(sort: params.sort, order: params.order, max: params.max, offset: params.offset) {
        if (params.searchText) {
            ilike("name",  "%${params.searchText}%")
        }

        eq("usState", params.state)
        eq("active", true)

        ne "id" , new DetachedCriteria(SiteResource).build {
            'in' ("resource", params.associatedResources.resource.id)
            'in' ("site", params.associatedResources.site.id)
        }
    }
```

I've also tried the following:

```
def siteResources = getSiteResourcesBySite(site).collect {
    it.resource
}

def resources = resource.findAllByRefugeAndActiveNotInList(refuge, true, siteResources, [sort:"name"])

return resources.list(sort: params.sort, order: params.order, max: params.max, offset: params.offset)
```

I hope this made sense; I'm still trying to figure out how the DetachedQuery works. If there is a better way to accomplish this task please enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

Criteria builder was not needed. Here's my solution:

```
def site = siteService.getSite(params.siteId)
def stateCode = site.study.state.code
def state= State.findByCode(stateCode )

List<Resource> associatedResources = siteResourceService.getAssociatedResourcesBySite(site).collect { it.id }

params.state = state
params.site = site
```

...

```
def getUnassociatedResourcesByState(params, List associatedResources) {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? Integer.parseInt(params.max) : 25, 100)
    params.offset =  params.offset ? params.offset : 0
    params.sort = params.sort ? params.sort : 'name'
    params.order = params.order == 'desc' ? params.order : 'asc'

    return Resource.findAllByStateAndActiveAndIdNotInList(params.state, true, associatedResources, [sort: params.sort, order: params.order, max: params.max, offset: params.offset])
}
```